# PHP MySQL - Notifications panel, update DB when dropdown is clicked

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple dropdown menu which displays notifications for my users. When there is a notification for the logged in user that was created before the user last checked their notifications (stored as notescheck in my user table), the notification drop down is highlighted. I want notescheck for that user to be updated when they click on the dropdown menu to see the list of notifications.

At the moment I can get it to update, but it happens every time the header is loaded so if the user gets a notification and then navigates to another page it automatically updates.

So my question is how do I execute this:

```
mysqli_query($db_conx, "UPDATE users SET notescheck=now() WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
```

But only when the user clicks the notifications dropdown in the header?

Here is the full code for my header if needed:

```
<div class="sticky_wrapper">
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

?>

<!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/cge/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/cge/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/cge/assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/cge/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/cge/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/cge/assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/cge/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/cge/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/cge/assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/cge/assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/cge/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/cge/assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/cge/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
    <!-- main js -->
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/cge/assets/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/cge/assets/slider/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>



    <!-- Typeahead -->
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#typeahead").typeahead({
                source: function(typeahead, query) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8888/cge/source.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: 'query=' + query,
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        async: false,
                        success: function(data) {
                            typeahead.process(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

<div style="padding-top: 60px;"></div>

<!-- WHITE USER STRIP -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">

    <?php
        if ($username) {
//display USER
            include('./php_includes/db_conx.php');
            $sql = "SELECT notescheck FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
            $notescheck = $row[0];
            $sql = "SELECT id FROM notifications WHERE username='$username' AND date_time > '$notescheck' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='$username' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade DESC";
            $friendquery = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            $friendnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($friendquery);
            if ($numrows == 0 && $friendnumrows == 0) {
                $notifications = '<i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>';
            } else {
                $notifications = '<i style="color:#3dca9c" class="fa fa-inbox"></i>';
                    }

//notifications panel
            $notification_list = "";
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE username LIKE BINARY '$username' AND date_time > '$notescheck' ORDER BY date_time DESC";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

            if($numrows < 1 && $friendnumrows < 1){
            $notification_list = "<li><a href='#'>You do not have any notifications</a></li>";
            } else {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $noteid = $row["id"];
            $initiator = $row["initiator"];
            $cardid = $row["cardid"];
            $app = $row["app"];
            $note = $row["note"];
            $date_time = $row["date_time"];
            $date_time = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($date_time));


            $notification_list .= "<li><a href='http://localhost:8888/cge/card.php?id=$cardid'>$note</a></li>";
            }
            while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($friendquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $friendrequester = $row2["user1"];

            $friendrequest_list .= "<li><a href='http://localhost:8888/cge/account/notifications.php'><strong>$friendrequester</strong> sent a friend request</a></li>";
            }
            }
                    mysqli_query($db_conx, "UPDATE users SET notescheck=now() WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
            echo
            "<ul class='nav'>
              <li class='dropdown'>
                <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>$username <b class='caret'></b></a>
                <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                  <li><a href='http://localhost:8888/cge/account/user.php?u=$username'>View Profile</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class='divider'></li>
                  <li><a href='http://localhost:8888/cge/account/logout.php'>Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class='nav pull-right'>
                <li class='dropdown'>".
                "<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>" . ($notifications) . "<b class='caret'></b></a>
                <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                  " . $notification_list;
                  if ($friendrequest_list){
                  echo "<li class='divider'></li>" . $friendrequest_list; }
                  echo "<li class='divider'></li>
                  <li><a href='http://localhost:8888/cge/account/notifications.php'>View all notifications</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>";
        }
        else
//diplay login or register button
            echo "<ul class='nav login-or-register'>
            <li><a href='http://localhost:8888/cge/account/login.php'>Login or Register</a></li>
           </ul>

           <ul class='nav pull-right'>
            <li><a href='#'>Get a Card Graded!</a></li>
           </ul>";

        if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == logout){
            echo "<body onload=\"window.location='http://localhost:8888/cge/index.php'\">"; 
            session_destroy();
        }
    ?>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- MAIN NAV & LOGO -->
    <div class="nav-second container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="logo span4">
                <img src="http://localhost:8888/cge/assets/img/logo.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="main-nav span8">
                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Browse Cards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Charts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">How-To Guide</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
                <div class="search-bar span8 pull-right">
                    <div class="search-bar-inner pull-right">
                    <form action='http://localhost:8888/cge/search.php' method='get'>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Card..." id="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" name ="keyname" value="<?php echo preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-\­.\(\)\s\!\?\,]/', '' ,$_GET['keyname']);?>"/>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>


        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JQuery for this as well. Send an ajax request to a file that only runs the update query.

```
$(".notifications").click(function(){
    $.post('update/notifications.php');
});
```

Where *update/notifications.php* looks like the following

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
//connect
mysqli_query($db_conx, "UPDATE users SET notescheck=now() WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
```

So the query will only be run when the user actually clicks the notifications. This is one way to do it, I guess there are others and honestly I'm not 100% sure you can use the session, but then you'd just send the username with the POST request.

Comment: Thanks dude, this is helping me out a lot. Ok, so I got the _update/notification.php_ page to work when manually navigated to, the session does work and it updates _notescheck_ . However, I can't get it to work via JQuery but I'm guessing I've just implemented it incorrectly (haven't had much experience with JQuery). I added this:

`<script>
  $(".notifications").click(function(){
    $.post('http://localhost:8888/cge/update/notifications.php');
});
</script>`

and added `class='notifications';` to the dropdown. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the function called when you clicked? Otherwise you might need to put that inside of `$(document).ready(function(){` or `$(document).loaded(function(){`. Also you need to check if the session is correctly retrieved in update/notifications.php

Comment: Perfect, `$(document).ready(function(){` did the trick. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just make another ajax call on the click of the notification panel and update the database and when you got the success response for the ajax make that particular notification in active.

Or if you want it to be disappear you can do it with jquery to remove html for that notification of you can reload the html of notification panel from the same ajax response

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answers, I just have a little suggestion that can optimize your code further. Instead of running 3 different queries to

- Get the last date notifications were checked (SELECT notescheck FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1)
- Get the id of a notification that has not been checked (SELECT id FROM notifications WHERE username='$username' AND date_time > '$notescheck' LIMIT 1)
- Get actual notification(s) that has not been checked (SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE username LIKE BINARY '$username' AND date_time > '$notescheck' ORDER BY date_time DESC)

You can combine all 3 into a single query that would fetch the notifications of that user for you. Then you can simply check if row(s) were returned, which would now determine what to display. The query is shown below

SELECT n.*
FROM notifications INNER JOIN users u
ON n.username = u.username
WHERE n.username = '$username'  /* or you can use "LIKE BINARY '$username'" if you like */
AND n.date_time > u.notescheck
ORDER BY n.date_time DESC